# Is it wise to target three different proposals for three different fellowships with three different supervisors/hosts?

Tags: ethics

I have options to apply for three different fellowships. I want to go for three different proposals with three different hosts. Is it wise and ethical to do so?

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't unethical. You aren't expected to be exclusive at this stage. Later on, however, if you get more than one offer, you may need to dance about a bit to stay honest with everyone.

Seems like a lot of work, though. Maybe overkill. Would you really be happy with any of them?